# Implementing ItemProcessListener for a chain of ItemProcessors

Tags: spring-batch

I am using Spring batch.
I have 2 Item Procesors which are used for doing the processing logic.

I have configured the listener for both ItemReader and ItemWriter.

I have used Spring Batch CompositeItemProcessor (org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor).

My Job configuration is as follows :-

```
<job id="SoDJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="step1">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="itemReader"  processor="SoDConflictProcessor" writer="SoDConflictExcelWriter"
                    commit-interval="1" />                  
            <listeners>
                    <listener ref="sodJobListener" />
                    <listener ref="SoDItemReaderListener" />
                    <listener ref="SoDItemWriterListener" />
            </listeners>                    
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>
```

My Processors are configured as :-

```
<bean id="SoDConflictProcessor"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor">
<property name="delegates">
<list>
<ref bean="SoDDataProcessor" />
<ref bean="SoDLogicProcessor" />
</list>
</property>
</bean>
```

How Can i write individual ItemProcessListener for both ItemProcessor (SoDDataProcessor and SoDLogicProcessor).

FYI :

1) SoDDataProcessor - implements `ItemProcessor<User, HashSet<String>>`.

2) SoDLogicProcessor - implements `ItemProcessor<HashSet<String>, HashSet<Object>>`

Hope this clears my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `CompositeItemProcessListener` but this doesn't fit your requirement because - I think - your request is to have `SoDDataProcessorListener` called when `SoDDataProcessor` process an item and `SoDLogicProcessorListener` called when the item transformed from previous step pass into `SoDLogicProcessor`.
This is not possible for two reasons:

1. `ItemProcessorListener` is called around your `CompositeItemProcessor` and not called around its delegated `ItemProcessor`s
2. `CompositeItemProcessListener` will run into a `ClassCastException` because is signature must be `CompositeItemProcessListener<User,HashSet<Object>>` and when receiving `HashSet<String>` will thrown an exception

You have to resolve in another way, this depends by your needs; I'll give you just an idea for your question, but you can also reconsider your design to achieve the same result

*My idea:*
Store intermediate transformed data in `StepExecutionContext`, write your own `ItemProcessorListener` that delegate each intermediate result to `SoDDataProcessorListener`, `SoDLogicProcessorListener` and others if you (will) have more and dispatch data to correct listener; in this way you can also write specific classes to mantain listeners separated.

Hope can help.

Comment: Thanks , i will try it out.Is their no other possible way in which one can call its delegated ItemProcessors instead of  ItemProcessorListener being called around CompositeItemProcessor.If not should i redesign the ItemProcessors as 1) SoDDataProcessor - implements ItemProcessor<User, HashSet<Object>>.

2) SoDLogicProcessor - implements ItemProcessor<HashSet<Object>, HashSet<Object>>..Will this work ?

Comment: You can call listener manually, but I think is not a good idea; better let spring-batch manage listener's lifecycle.
Can works, just try (but IMHO has too high coesion between processor's <T,S> and listeners <T,S> chain. Hope you can understand, English is not my native language.